# Github Windows "invalid path" message

Tags: vb.net, github

Four of my Github repositories get an "invalid path" error when I try to commit to master on Github Desktop (Windows). They've been working for years. I have copied the folders to and from a laptop recently, but I have also done that in the past with no problems.

```
error: invalid path 'qbug/'
error: qbug/: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: Unable to process path qbug/
```

How can I fix this, and how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.5